# A single onChange listener on a <form> tag

Tags: reactjs

I was just playing a bit with a more generic way of dealing with form data, and figured that setting a single `onChange` listener on the wrapping form tag should work for all changes to input fields.

And indeed, it does - no surprise there. Events get called, I know what changed by inspecting `event.target.name` and can update state accordingly. Fully as expected.

However, React doesn't seem to like it and spams the well known "You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler" console warning.

Would there be any other reason for not doing this, apart from the console warning? It seems to eliminate a lot of duplication React otherwise gets criticised about.

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        name: 'Default Name',
        number: 12,
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { crashLogo } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <form onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} />
                    <input type="number" name="number" value={this.state.number} />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Just for clarity: I'm not asking for alternative solutions, I know I can set the same change listener directly on every input, use `redux-form`, own wrapper components with `context` magic and so on...

Comment: In order to avoid duplication you can do something like this:
`const inputs = [{ name: 'name', type: 'text'}, { name: 'number', type: 'number' }];` and in your render `inputs.map(value => <input type={value.type} name={value.name} value={this.state[value.name} onChange={this.handleChane} />`

Comment: I totally like doing this and as long as there are no complex validations on field value change, its fine. But if the form is complex enough and involves some complex validations on the fields, the handleChange function will get bigger. In that case, its better to have separate handler function to handle each change separately. Basically following Single Responsibility Principle. :)

Comment: there is an [old talk about it](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1118)